# Change in Amplitude of motion in SHM when Constant Force is applied

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

The Question goes as follows:

[image]

NOTE:

> Though the Question mentions $A_2$ to be Acceleration, please treat it to be the New Amplitude (since I have my conceptual doubt over that part only)

Now, I understand that the Time Period of the SHM remains unaffected even after the action of Pseudo Force on the Block (since it is not a Restoring Force), and I also understand that the Equilibrium Position of the Block changes due to that Constant Pseudo Force.

But I don't have fair enough idea whether the Amplitude of the SHM changes due to the action of Constant Force or not. 
 
So I would like to know whether it changes or not, and if it does, then it what fashion? (If possible, demonstrate using equations)

Comment: The problem is mis-stated. $A_1$ is defined as an amplitude and $A_2$ is defined as an acceleration.

Comment: Yes, that part is misstated. But since I have my conceptual doubt about that new Amplitude, that error becomes irrelevant (as I have now mentioned there).
Thanks for reminding me that part!

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, the hanging mass is immersed in a fluid of lower density. Fluid friction is going to cause the amplitude to decrease over time. It would appear that when comparing two sets of conditions which start with the same amplitude, we are to decide if the pseudo force will cause a change in the rate at which the amplitude decreases. The buoyant force does not increase as much as the effective weight, so there will be a shift in the equilibrium position. That should not effect the friction. There will also be an increase in the fluid pressure against the surfaces of the mass. I do not know if that will effect the friction.

Comment: I understood your point, but please do consider the Fluid to be **Ideal** (no viscous force/friction), since it has nothing to do with my conceptual doubt. I just want to know that if there is some sort of similar situation where we apply Constant External Force, does it change Amplitude of SHM or just the equilibrium position.